# Blushing animation

Tags: animation

Can anyone tell me how to animate the face of a character looking at the camera and gradually getting a blush. I am amazed that I cannot find any answers on this and I have tried all the stuff about animating materials with AnimAll etc

All I want to do is make my model go red in the face over 10 seconds. No movement, just a change of colour.

Comment: Hi. You said you "tried all the stuff about animating materials", what happened when you tried this and what didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, Ray. Moonboots' answer did thre trick.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you want this to happen. If you want for example the cheek to blush, you could do it this way:

- Unwrap your face with *Smart UV Project* mode.

[image]

- Create a blank image in the *UV Editor*, it will be your mask. Create a material with this image uploaded in an *Image Texture* node.

[image]

- In the 3D View, switch to *Texture Paint* mode, choose a black brush and begin to paint the area where the face is supposed to blush.

[image]

- In the *Node Editor*, mix the skin color with the blush color, use the image you've created as a mask. Your character now has red cheek. To make the blush appear you need a second *Mix Shader* before the *Material Output*.

[image]

- Now when you move the last *Mix Shader* factor it makes the blush appear gradually.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for scrapbook-worthy tips. 

Comment: Thanks, Moonboots. This worked and I was able to keyframe the changes by hovering over the Fac: section in the Materials property panel and hitting " I " on the keyboard.